# Download data from file without extension

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, package

I have a flat file without extension.

**Ex:** `T_D_FD_TESTUA_QWE_00_G1520160829103`

First part of the file name is unchangeable - `T_D_FD_TESTUA_QWE_`
I need to find files in a folder and downloaded it into database.
I've created a **ForeachLoopContainer** with **ScriptTask** and **Dataflow Task**.
Scrip task has code to identifi file: `string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"\\wuakyib332\!_Download\", "T_D_FD_TESTUA_QWE_*");`

but it work also on other files in the directory.

How to chek file in the folder using mask and download it?

Comment: Call `Path.GetExtension` on each file and just exclude those with a non-empty extension?

Comment: As Jon says - just use Directory.GetFiles(myPath) and if(Path.GetExtension(file)==""){}

Comment: Pls chek my script below.

Answer (score 0):

is that corect script?

```
public void Main()
        {
             string myPath = @"\\wsdkdib00\!_Download\";
              Directory.GetFiles(myPath);
              if (Path.GetExtension(myPath) == "T_D_FD_TESTUA_QWE_")
              {
                  Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
              }
        }
```